# Laravel create function insert only some of the fields in DB

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have socialite login for facebook and google. I'm trying to store values in db. Some of them are stored and some no. I think I have tried everything, but can't find problem and solution.

I have function:

```
public function CreateUser($user, $provider)
{
  $authUser = User::where('social_id', $user->id)->first();
  if($authUser)
  {
    return $authUser;
  }
  $token = $this->generateRandomString();
  return User::create([
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'social' => $provider,
        'social_id' => $user->id,
        'username' => $this->user_slug($user->name),
        'user_token' => $token,
        'earnings' => 0,
        'user_type' => 'vendor',
        'verified' => 1,

    ]);

}
```

All Values except social and social_id are stored in database. I tried to store different values in different fields.

For example, if I store $provider value in 'name' field it works. if I try to store $provider value or any other value in 'social' field. DB dosn't store it. Same for 'social_id' field.

1. I tried saving same value in different fields - It works
2. I tried to save different values in fields 'social' and 'social_id' - It dosn't work.
3. I tried to rename these 2 fields - Still dosn't work
4. If I edit these fields from "phpmyadmin" then it works.
5. I tried to set fields with different options - It dosn't change anything

[DB Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5SzC.png)

Comment: Go Storage/Logs/laravel.log see what's the exact problem you face

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add 'social' and 'social_id' in $fillable array in User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the $fillable property on the model. For example, let's make the name attribute of our User model mass assignable:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['social', 'social_id'];
}
```